# JBoss EAP migration 6.3 to 7.1

Tags: jboss, migration

I'm trying to migrate my JBoss eap 6.3 to JBoss eap 7.1, using a jboss migration tool, but the jboss-server-migration.sh is giving me illegalargumentexception: failed to retrieve server SOURCE

https://gist.github.com/jj110178/80616755c0335c2090d4256d8c322bb2

I'm tryin to follow this guide

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/migration_guide/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/using_the_jboss_server_migration_tool

But unfortunately can't even get to run the migration tool

here is my directory structure

/c/Users/Username/dev/migration/jboss-eap-7.1

/c/Users/Username/dev/migration/jboss-eap-6.3

Hopefully someone can guide me on this

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't see -s or -t in the instructions.  Try one of the versions in the guide.  This one is when using a properties file.

```
EAP_HOME/bin/jboss-server-migration.sh --source EAP_PREVIOUS_HOME --environment path/to/my-server-migration.properties
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/using_the_jboss_server_migration_tool/configuring_the_migration_tool

Comment: thanks djb, -s is equals to --source same as the -t if you try to execute batch script without arguments